# Building vs2015 sdl2 x64 Sucess, But no Window/Contex

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, 64-bit, sdl, sdl-2

I wam migrating from vs2012 to vs2015.

I built sdl2, no compiler linker errors, SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) succeeds but everything after returns 0.
No window, and no context.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Was [`SDL_GetError()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) not returning anything informative?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be damned, what a rookie mistake.

Indeed, the error after creating the window indicates  that SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED cannot be used as a flag anymore. (Was it allowed before?)

I thank you for your hint.

Comment: `SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED` can go in the `x` or `y` arguments to `SDL_CreateWindow()`.